# How to create singleton task in Luigi?

Tags: python, singleton, job-scheduling, luigi

I need to run once a day task A. At 0:00:00 for specificity.
But task execution can take more then 24 hours. In this case, I should not rerun the task - I should skip execution.

How can I implement such singleton task in Luigi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[erikbern commented on 27 Aug 2015 at GitHub](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/1168#issuecomment-135426458):

> Tasks are already singletons (instantiated with the same parameters).